# Release a cocatouch framework

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, frameworks, distribute

I have made a library that make by swift cocoa touch framework, and now I need to export it to file .framework that can import for another project. In fact, I'm workground that copy the framework from product forder, but I think it is not a correctly solution (such as it may be archive and export, but I can't do it). Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you made a swift framework and want to include the framework to another project.
You can just drag the framework .xcodeproj from Finder to your new project and start using it.

Comment: Yes, in the fact, I make a workground as you say. But I don't think it's the formal solution. I need to release the framework and public for another developer.